# Firebase createUser and signIn gives warnings in console - react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I was building a login cum signup screen in react-native where it takes email and password from the user and tries to signin using the firebase call

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

and if it fails to login then I create a new account for the user using the call

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

When I run the app on emulator and try to sign in it works fine but I get a yellow box warning saying

> Deprecated firebase.User.prototype.signInWithEmailAndPassword in favor
>   of firebase.User.prototype.signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword

I get a similar type of error for the createUser method. What difference will it make if I replace my methods with the ones suggested by the warnings?

Also I get a warning for the firebase initialization call which is 
`firebase.initializeApp(config);` saying

> Deprecation: Calling 'InitializeApp()' for apps that are already
>   initialised natively is unnecessary, use 'firebase.app()' instead to
>   access the already initialized default app instance.

But when I actually change the initialization call to `firebase.app(config)` it throws me an error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function.

For now, I have completely disabled the yellow box. Please let me know if there is any other workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

Please update to the latest firebase SDK version. Some of the sign-in method will be deprecated eventually. The warning is to let you switch to new APIs before it's deprecated so it won't break your app when we deprecated them.

Comment: Is there any difference between the methods like the new ones say retrieve data. Does it make any difference to the data returned?

Comment: It depends on the version you are using. Before v5.0, signIn methods without 'retrieveData' only return a `user` object and those with 'retrieveData' return `AuthResult` . After 5.0, they both return `AuthResult`, but methods with retrieveData will be deprecated.

Comment: Oh yes my app uses any version above 4.1.0 so I guess it installs the latest version only but then why does it ask me to use retrieveData when they are being deprecated in the newer versions.

Comment: I think you are using version <= 5.0. We tried to let people use the methods which return `AuthResult` while signInWith*** only return `User` before 5.0.

Comment: Oh I guess that's the case with me. I get a user object that has the uid and stuff. Thanks for the answer but then what about the initialize method?

Comment: are you talking about `firebase.initializeApp(config);`? That remains the same.

Comment: Yes, but if it is the same then why do I get a warning on that?